# No data in ga_sessions_

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I'm doing some querys at BigQuery and appears this ERROR: 'Query returned zero records.'
I'm reviewing the table from the GA datasets and see a lot of tables at the ga_sessions_intraday_, when I introduce a date range at query, appears this error. 
When the query runs, the data is not equal that the data from GA.

Thanks!!

```
SELECT
  hits.contentgroup.contentgroup2 CampaignGrouping,
  custd.value member_PK,
  'Web' Canal,
  'ES' AS country_id,
  SUM(hits.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews2) VistasUnicas
FROM
  `bigquery-aaaaa-11111.222222.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(customdimensions) custd,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE
  1 = 1
  AND PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', REGEXP_EXTRACT(_table_suffix, r'.*_(.*)')) BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2017-03-28') AND TIMESTAMP('2017-03-30')
  AND custd.index=30
  and hits.contentGroup.contentGroup2 <> '(not set)'
  AND custd.value <> 'null'
  AND hits.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews2 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  1, 2
ORDER BY 5 ASC
```

Comment: Try checking the output from the `REGEXP_EXTRACT`. I suspect that it's not returning strings in the format that you are expecting.

Comment: Does it work if you use this FROM clause:
`bigquery-aaaaa-11111.222222.ga_sessions` ? (notice I just removed the final "_" string)

Comment: Hi @Will yes!! Works!
Can you explain me, how to concatenate or make the union from more querys with the same information but from others datasets?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @HéctorIbáñez, to UNION tables from other datasets I think the only way is to first add all tables using `union all` and then you work with the data.
Also, I just had a problem similar to yours and asked here in SO, make sure to check it out to see if you are not having the same issue as I had: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942988/bigquery-ga-exported-with-duplicated-rows. Basically my wildcard selection as retrieving duplicated tables as intraday tables are no longer being deleted (not quire sure why nor if this will keep this way)

Comment: Hi @Will thanks, but don't works the UNION ALL function. When i put in the query don't run and appears the next error: Error: SELECT list expression references hits.contentgroup.contentgroup2 which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [2:3]
Where put this function at the query?

Comment: Hi @HéctorIbáñez, I recommend you to ask a new question on SO describing with more details the problem you are having (maybe something went wrong in the construction of the query itself)

Comment: @Will done it :D