# BigQuery GA Exported with Duplicated Rows

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

We have been trying to explain why this happened in all of our datasets but so far we had no success.

We observed that starting on 18 April our *ga_sessions* dataset had for the most part duplicated entries (like 99% of rows). As an example, I tested this query:

```
SELECT
  fullvisitorid fv,
  visitid v,
  ARRAY(
  SELECT
    AS STRUCT hits.*
  FROM
    UNNEST(hits) hits
  ORDER BY
    hits.hitnumber) h
FROM
  `dafiti-analytics.40663402.ga_sessions*`
WHERE
  1 = 1
  AND REGEXP_EXTRACT(_table_suffix, r'.*_(.*)') BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY))AND FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY))
ORDER BY
  fv,
  v
LIMIT
  100
```

And the result was:

[image]

We tried to investigate when this began to happen, so I ran this query:

```
SELECT
  date,
  f,
  COUNT(f) freq from(
  SELECT
    date,
    fullvisitorid fv,
    visitid v,
    COUNT(CONCAT(fullvisitorid, CAST(visitid AS string))) f
  FROM
    `dafiti-analytics.40663402.ga_sessions*`
  WHERE
    1 = 1
    AND PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', REGEXP_EXTRACT(_table_suffix, r'.*_(.*)')) BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2017-04-01')
    AND TIMESTAMP('2017-04-30')
  GROUP BY
    fv,
    v,
    date )
GROUP BY
  f,
  date
ORDER BY
  date,
  freq DESC
```

And we found that for 3 of our projects it started on day 18 April but in accounts related to LATAM data we started seeing duplicated rows just recently as well.

We also checked if in our GCP Console something was logged but couldn't find anything.

Is there some mistake we could have made that caused the duplication in the ga_sessions export? We checked our analytics tracking but it seems to be working just fine. Also there's no modification we did these days that explain it as well.

If you need more info please let me know.

Comment: Can you include the `_TABLE_SUFFIX` in the select list and make sure that it's as you expect for the rows?

Comment: hi @ElliottBrossard, just tested what you suggested and now I could see the error! As the intradays tables no longer are being deleted from the dataset so the selection is bringing both tables (ga_sessions and ga_sessions_intraday for same days). Just wondering, is there a recommended approach to select only intraday tables that are not duplicated in the where clause? Tnx for the help!

Comment: See if the answer that I added helps. I suspect that you just need to include a longer prefix with the wildcard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to match only the intraday or non-intraday tables. For intraday:

```
`dafiti-analytics.40663402.ga_sessions_intraday*`
```

For non-intraday:

```
`dafiti-analytics.40663402.ga_sessions_2017*`
```

The important part is to include enough of the prefix to match the desired tables.

Comment: Thanks for the help Elliott! One problem we still have is if we want to query intraday and ga_sessions in the same query (what I plan on doing is selecting intraday for the previous 2 days and ga_sessions for the rest)

Comment: You can still do this: either use UNION ALL of the two wildcard table prefixes, or have the wildcard include both prefixes and then use an OR of two filters on _TABLE_SUFFIX in the WHERE clause. It's a bit tricky to explain in a comment, but hopefully that suggestion makes sense :)

Comment: I added this clause to the where:
`  AND
  CASE
    WHEN (REGEXP_CONTAINS(_table_suffix, 'intraday') AND REGEXP_EXTRACT(_table_suffix, r'.*_(.*)') BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY))AND FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY))) THEN TRUE
    WHEN (NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(_table_suffix, 'intraday')
    AND REGEXP_EXTRACT(_table_suffix, r'.*_(.*)') BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY))AND FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY))) THEN TRUE
  END`