# How to select google analytics segment in google big query? SQL

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery, tableau-api, segment

I create Google Analytics data source in Tableau.
The data source has the segment by "new user".
[image]

Now, I would like to push the Google Analytics in Google Bigquery and create the same data source in Tableau by creating a data source from Google Bigquery.

After checking the GA data source in Google Bigquery project.
There is no segment in Bigquery.

How to query by segment "new user" in Google Bigquery??

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can look at [BigQuery GA Schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en) to see all fields that are exported there.

The field `totals.newVisits` has what you are looking for:

```
select
hits.transaction.transactionid tid,
date,
totals.pageviews pageviews,
hits.item.itemquantity item_qtd,
hits.transaction.transactionrevenue / 1e6 rvn,
totals.bounces bounces,
fullvisitorid fv,
visitid v,
totals.timeonsite tos,
totals.newVisits new_visit
FROM
    `project_id.dataset_id.ga_sessions*`,
    unnest(hits) hits
  WHERE
    1 = 1
    AND PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', REGEXP_EXTRACT(_table_suffix, r'.*_(.*)')) BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2017-05-10')
    AND TIMESTAMP('2017-05-10')
group by 
tid, date, pageviews, item_qtd, rvn, bounces, fv, v, tos, new_visit
```

Notice that this field is defined in the session level.

Comment: Thanks a lot. May I check with you something?  totals.newVisits: Total number of new users in session (for convenience). If this is the first visit, this value is 1, otherwise it is null.  By referring to the GA pie chart, it shows new visitor 117Session (88%), Return visitor 16session (12%). The data I get from bigquery, it does not match from GA pie

Comment: Make sure that you are not selecting ga_sessions and intraday tables with the wildcard I used (check Elliott's answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942988/bigquery-ga-exported-with-duplicated-rows/43948806?noredirect=1#comment74992000_43948806 )
Other than that, also make sure to use `totals.visits =1` in the where clause. Our numbers in our project also don't exactly match our GA but are still similar.