# Firebase + BigQuery - Duplicate events

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, duplicates, firebase-analytics

I noticed there are thousands of events duplicated in the events tables of BigQuery (in an integration with Firebase).

My definition of duplicated is: 2 or more events that share the same data in all these fields:

```
event_timestamp, event_name, user_pseudo_id, app_info.id, device.advertising_id
```

It happens for automatically collected events, and also custom events. I found some of the parameters that could differ from one result to the other are (what make those events different):

```
event_server_timestamp_offset, geo.continent, geo.country
```

I guess there is no reason for a duplicated event at the same moment, same user, same app, same device, but one event is `geo.continent=America` and the other `geo.continent=Asia`.

Any thoughts why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: your input data?

Comment: Hello @DarkRob What do you refer with "your input data?"

Comment: Based on this comment (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942988/bigquery-ga-exported-with-duplicated-rows) I have a feeling that somedays intraday table is not deleted and the next day you have duplicated data in your shard-day table. But I have no idea how to check this idea(

Answer (score 2):

Google's explanation is that Firebase data duplication in BigQuery is mostly related to network issues on the client's side that cause events to be buffered and sent twice.

However there is a way to deduplicate these events by using **event_server_timestamp_offset**. This field is difference between the time the event was sent to Google's server and when it was received.
This means that given the same event_timestamp, event_name and user_pseudo_id you could take only the event with lower event_server_timestamp_offset to have a correct result.

You can also safely delete duplicates records from your event table.

Sorry I can't share sources for this because the answer came from Google Analytics support, as I was encountering the same issue.

Comment: `event_server_timestamp_offset` is null for my events associated to a google analytics 4 property...

Comment: Any chance you have a link to Google's explanation?

Answer (score 0):

We use the `QUALIFY` clause for deduplication Firebase events in BigQuery:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `project.dataset.events_*`
QUALIFY
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY
      user_pseudo_id,
      event_name,
      event_timestamp,
      TO_JSON_STRING(event_params)
    ) = 1
```

Qualifying columns:

```
  - name: user_pseudo_id
    description:  Autogenerated pseudonymous ID for the user -
                  Unique identifier for a specific installation of application on a client device,
                  e.g. "938642951.1666427135".
                  All events generated by that device will be tagged with this pseudonymous ID,
                  so that you can relate events from the same user together.

  - name: event_name
    description:  Event name, e.g. "app_launch", "session_start", "login", "logout" etc.

  - name: event_timestamp
    description:  The time (in microseconds, UTC) at which the event was logged on the client,
                  e.g. "1666529002225262".

  - name: event_params
    description:  A repeated record (ARRAY) of the parameters associated with this event.
```